# Mootools addClass for styling

Tags: javascript, mootools, styling

So I've been learning JavaScript for a while now, and have just started to incorporate a framework. I chose MooTools for various reasons, but that's a bit off topic.

So, my first little bit of code I have created to add a class to li elements to which relate to a style on mouseover, and remove it on mouseleave. I've done this numerous times in JavaScript no worries, but can't get it working using MooTools.

HTML snippet:

```
    <ul id="navBar">
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS Framework snippet:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {

$('navBar').getElements('a').addEvent({
    mouseenter:function(){
        $(this).addClass('navHover');
    },
    mouseleave:function(){
        $(this).removeClass('navHover');
    }
});
});
```

CSS snippet:

```
.navHover {
color: #FFF;
}
```

Possibly I'm not implementing the framework correctly, maybe I should just revert back to plain old JavaScript?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply left out an "s". :-)

```
   $('navBar').getElements('a').addEvents({
                                        ^ here
```

If you meant to do `addEvent`, then you should know it can only add a singular event, so if would have to be: `$('navBar').getElements('a').addEvent("mouseenter", function() { ... });` As you wrote up, it is the right syntax for `addEvents`.

Source (although I think this issue was a typo): http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Event#Element:addEvents

and jsfiddle working example: http://jsfiddle.net/pxLTX/

Comment: hahaha, I checked it for hours and it was a typo! Thank you so much.